# Limpar tela após transição - IONIC app

Tags: android, angularjs, ios, ionic, app

Estou criando um app com ionic e angular, e estou fazendo uso de tabs. Tenho 5 tabs, e umas delas exibe uma página "Menu", essa página contém a listagem de outras páginas que não estão nas tabs, cada item dessa listagem redireciona pra uma página diferente.

O meu problema é que quando eu clico na tab Menu, ela exibe a listagem e eu seleciono a página que quero ir, porém se eu clicar em outra tab, e depois clicar na tab Menu de novo, ela não fará mais a listagem dos itens, e sim exibirá a última página que eu tinha acessado através do Menu.

Pra ficar mais claro::: 
clico na tab Menu/
vejo a listagem de itens/ 
seleciono o item Clientes/ 
sou redirecionado para a página de Clientes/
quando clico em outra tab (exemplo: Produtos), sou redirecionado para páginas de Produtos/
porém quando clico na tab Menu de novo, ela não exibe a página com os itens, mas sim a página de Clientes, que eu tinha acessado anteriormente.

Não acho que exista erro no meu código, porém gostaria de saber se existe alguma função do ionic que possa usar pra fazer esse "clean" depois que sair da página, tentei utilizar o ionViewDidLeave, porém não deu certo.

Comment: O que está acontecendo é que você não está finalizando o componente quando está trocando de tab. O Ionic possui alguns métodos do ciclo de vida. (Dá uma olhadinha) https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/ .... 
No teu caso utilizar você poderia fechar o componente anterior no ionViewWillLeave com o método pop do NavController...
Tenho um exemplo nesta página: https://github.com/brognilucas/top-weather/blob/master/src/pages/city-details/city-details.ts

Comment: Criei o ionVieWillLeave() dentro do ts do Menu, porém não deu certo.


ionVieWillLeave(){
        this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
    }

Comment: Martin, tenta colocar um console log no ionViewWillLeave? Pode ser que ele não esteja chamando por ser apenas uma troca de aba.

Comment: o console log está funcionando normalmente, o problema não seria o this.navCtrl.popToRoot() ?

Comment: Tenta dar apenas um navCtrl.pop() sem ser o root ... achei que ele não estivesse entrando no método de saída da tela. Se não funcionar somente com o pop eu não sei agora o que pode ser  :(